# Searching multiple MySQL tables from an HTML form and returning the data in alphabetical order

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

I'd like to search 3 separate tables I've created from 1 form and return the data in alphabetical order. Currently I can search 3 tables separately with use of a drop-down box (from my form) to select a table but I've fallen short at querying them simultaneously and returning all the data in alphabetical order. I've been trying to solve it but I'm struggling a lot.

Currently what my program searches through separate tables for what the user previously input into my form. Now I would like to be able to search through all my tables in 1 go and return the information in alphabetical order, meaning some values from tables might be spread out.

I have 3 tables: "Insecttable", "birdtable" and "butterflytable"

There are 3 controllers: "ControllerInsectTable", ControllerBirdTable and "ControllerButterflyTable"

I'm trying to make another controller: "ControllerAllTables" that can search through all tables.

**HTML:**

```
<form name="searchForm" id="searchForm" method="POST" action="ControllerAllTables.php"> 
  Search for: <input type="text" name="aSearch"> 
  <input type="submit" name="searchButton" value="Search">
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
    // Collect Data
// If an input has been given
if(isset($_POST["aSearch"])) {
  $searchq = $_POST["aSearch"];
  $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq); //Can only search words

// Select statements if keywords match
$sql = "SELECT * FROM insecttable WHERE insectName LIKE '%$searchq%'";
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM butterflytable WHERE butterflyName LIKE '%$searchq%'";
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM birdtable WHERE birdName LIKE '%$searchq%'";
}

// Tests if the code been inserted
if ($conn->query($sql && $sql1 &&sql2)=== TRUE){
  echo "The rows you have searched for are:";
} else {
  echo "Connection failed: ";
  echo $conn->error;
}

// Show fields
$result = $conn->query($sql && $sql1 &&sql2);

// Output data of each row
if ($result-> num_rows> 0) {
  readfile("ViewReturn.html");
  while($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
    // echo "ID: ".$row["id"]. "<br>";
    echo "Insect: ".$row["insectName"]. "<br><br>";
    echo "Bird: ".$row["birdName"]. "<br><br>";
    echo "Butterfly: ".$row["butterflyName"]. "<br><br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
```

I cut out some of the bits of my code that didn't affect my question, like making connections and such.

At the moment, I have no idea how to return values in order, and I'm seriously stuck at searching multiple tables from one query. I've looked at "joins" but I really don;'t understand them.

As you can tell I'm not very good at PHP, and I hope I can soon rid it from my life. I've been completely unsuccessful in this section of my program and I'm looking for help and criticism. I know it's a lot to ask but I'm really stuck, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the `UNION` operator to combine the query results, being sure to order the data **after** it has been combined. This can affect performance, but hopefully your result sets aren't too large.

```
SELECT name  -- because we NEVER use select *
FROM
(
    SELECT insectName AS name FROM InsectTable WHERE insectName LIKE '$searchq%'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT butterflyName AS name FROM ButterflyTable WHERE butterflyName LIKE '$searchq%'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT birdName AS name FROM BirdTable WHERE birdName LIKE '$searchq%'
)
```

Also, you might want to consider a redesign of the database. If the items in your tables are all related then they are effectively a super class. If you Google "SQL super class design" you should be able to find some good patterns for this.

Also, appending the word "Table" to the end of all of your table names is not something that is usually done. If your table holds data about insects then it's "Insect" or "Insects" (I'll ignore the singular/plural debate for now). The fact that it's a table is already self-evident.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I'm still a little confused with a few things:

- Was the "name" identifier that you used already assigned as a variable or is it a keyword?

- Also does this replace my current $sql statement?

Sorry for being so clueless, it's just that SQL/PHP confuses me a bit

Also thank you for the suggestion, I'm currently looking into designing my database using super class design :¬)

Comment: The "name" is simply an alias. I'm basically telling SQL that for this particular query use "name" as this column's name instead of the actual column name.

Comment: Thanks for the help Tom, I've made some changes to my DB. The only problem I have now is that I don't really know where that SQL statement fits in with my code, should I just replace my current $SQL statement with that

Comment: I don't know enough about your application to answer that, but if you have a specific question then you can start another question on here.

Comment: Should I show you what I mean by posting another question within this question? As in through the "answer your question"?

Comment: You should post a completely new question. The site is designed so that other people down the road can use these questions/answers to find answers to their own questions. That's more difficult if a question has extended conversations and multiple questions/answers.